# CMake link directory passing when compiling shared library

Tags: cmake

Say I have C project with the following structure (simplified):

```
|- CMakeLists.txt   <- This is root CMake
|- lib
    |- <some source files>
    |- CMakeLists.txt   <- CMake file for building the library
|- demo
    |- <some source files>
    |- CMakeLists.txt   <- CMake for building demo apps
|- extra_lib
    |- <some source files>
    |- CMakeLists.txt   <- CMake for building supplementary library
```

Now, I want to build my library (living in `lib`) as a shared library to be used by demo apps from `demo` directory.

Additional library, that can not be a part of my library (it is essentially a wrapper for some C++ external library) is also to be compiled as a shared library and then linked to my library.

I have a problem with including dependencies for additional library. In its `CMakeLists.txt` I've defined `link_directories` to point location where `.so` libs are stored and then `target_link_libraries` to point which should be linked. At the end I did export target.

```
include_directories(${EXTERNAL_DIR}/include)
link_directories(${EXTERNAL_DIR}/lib)

add_library(extra_lib SHARED extra_lib.cpp)

target_link_libraries(extra_lib
  some_lib
)

export(TARGETS extra_lib FILE extra_lib.cmake)
```

The point is that when I try to compile `lib` and link it against `extra_lib` I get an error that `some_lib` is not found what I guess means that `link_directories` is local to the `extra_lib`.

Now, question is how can I make it propagate together with dependencies? I'd like it to work in the way that adding `extra_lib` as subdirectory and as a dependency for my lib would automatically add linked directories from `extra_lib` to the `lib` linking process.

The linking process would look like:

(some external library) --> extra_lib --> lib --> demo app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/link_directories.html?highlight=link_directories) state that commands like `include_directories` and `link_directories` are rarely necessary. In fact, it is almost always better to use `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` instead.

Secondly, the reason your approach fails is because you need to let CMake know about the existence of `some_lib`. You can do this like so:

```
add_library(some_lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(some_lib
    PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${EXTERNAL_DIR}/lib/libsome_lib.so)
```

Then, afterwards:

```
target_link_libraries(extra_lib some_lib)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!